# httpd: Cannot make httpd to run under apache user

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, httpd

I followed a few guides.

- httpd is installed, running the service using sudo / so its as root, it works.

I have an apache user and group, and /etc/init.d/httpd is under apache:apache already.

But all I get is:

```
 Restarting httpd (via systemctl):  Failed to issue method call: Access denied
                                                           [FAILED]
```

This is my httpd folder `ll -h`

```
[alazarev@alazarev-asus etc]$ ll -h /etc/httpd/
total 8.0K
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache apache 4.0K Jun  1 23:55 conf
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache apache 4.0K Jun  1 23:55 conf.d
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache   19 Jun  1 23:55 logs -> ../../var/log/httpd
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache   27 Jun  1 23:55 modules -> ../../usr/lib/httpd/modules
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache   19 Jun  1 23:55 run -> ../../var/run/httpd
[alazarev@alazarev-asus etc]$
```

I am still not getting a clue where the problem is. By the way, my user has apache group appended:

```
[alazarev@alazarev-asus etc]$ id
uid=500(alazarev) gid=500(alazarev) groups=500(alazarev),10(wheel),48(apache) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
[alazarev@alazarev-asus etc]$
```

As you can see guys, I'm on: `groups=500(alazarev),10(wheel),48(apache)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I'm reading your question correctly, but if Apache is binding to port 80/443, it has to be started as root--only root can bind to ports < 1024.  Once it's started, though, it'll become whatever user/group you have defined in your apache configuration.  ie:

> User foo
>
> Group bar